# WordPress Gutenberg RichText, how can I set a default value with source: 'children' when using `multiline="p"`?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

While registering a new block, I cannot set a default value if using a `RichText` with a `multiline` tag

```js
  attributes: {
    header: {
      type: 'string',
      source: 'text',
      selector: 'h2',
      default: 'default',
    },
    text: {
      type: 'array',
      source: 'children',
      selector: 'div',
      default: 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet',

//    also tested, same result
//    default: ['Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet', 'test', 'test2'],
//    default: () => <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>,
//    default: [() => <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>],

    },
  },
  edit: ({ attributes: { header, text }, setAttributes }) => {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps()

    return (
      <div {...blockProps}>
        <RichText tagName="h2" placeholder={'Header'} onChange={header => setAttributes({ header })} value={header} />
        <RichText
          tagName="div"
          multiline="p"
          placeholder={'Write here the description'}
          onChange={text => setAttributes({ text })}
          value={text}
        />
      </div>
    )
  },
```

If I remove the `multiline="p"` line, I see the default text, but with it I don't see anything

Where's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative simplified way using the attributes to set a default for RichText with `multiline="p"` is:

```
    attributes: {
    ...
    text: {
        type: 'string', // changed from array
        source: 'children',
        selector: 'div',
        default: [<p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>, <p>test</p>, <p>test2</p>]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to do it by using what you gather when you edit manually the text

```js
default: [
  { type: 'p', props: { children: ['Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet'] } },
  { type: 'p', props: { children: ['test'] } },
],
```